# How to reverse the elements in numpy.ndarray Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy.ndarray in Python has the following elements e.g[[-0.85] [ 0.95]]. How can I reverse it so it can be [ [ 0.95][-0.85]]. Keep in mind that the length always two but for sure the values are changing.

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[-0.85]
[ 0.95]]
```

Comment: See for example https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy.flip() should do the job

```
array = numpy.flip(array)
```

returns

```
[[ 0.95] [-0.85]]
```